# Difference between IIS requests and interactions in MongoDB

Tags: xdb

During log-file investigation I've found a big difference between the IIS-log and the interactions collection in MongoDB.

I've started to log the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` within IIS and extract the values. The cookie in IIS-log looks like this: **SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=fe33e963e81f43eb8a578fe40690e80d|True**

For visitors with a cookie, Sitecore was able to start the tracking. The cookie-value is the ContactID value of a MongoDB interaction.
Then I run a query against the MongoDB to check for the cookie-value. The query looks like this:
**db.Interactions.find({"ContactId" : CSUUID("fe33e963e81f43eb8a578fe40690e80d")})**

But I can only find interaction entries for just 30% of all the cookie-values from the IIS log!

Something prevents Sitecore from saving all sessions to MongoDB. The problematic requests are not from any bot. Within Sitecore debug-level log, I can see the tracking starts but now an entry for serializing to MongoDB after session expiration.

Comment: Thanks for the description! The above is pretty dense though and a little tough to follow. You may want to try splitting it up into paragraphs to make it a little easier to read through. Also, can you clarify your question at the beginning or the end? It's not super clear what you are asking. Thanks! :)

Comment: Try disabling xDB robot detection by setting `Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots` and `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` to `false` in the ***Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config***. If all interactions are saved after this, that would mean that many of your contact visitors are recognized as robots.

Comment: Maybe you are right, @DmytroShevchenko. It makes sence anyway. I was expecting some log entry in debug-level if a contact is recognized as robot. Thaught i've seen something in a Sitecore processor...but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @StephanSchrader Have you had a chance to verify if my guess was right?